# Error with gradlew: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, bash, gradlew

After committing my project's `gradlew` file from my Windows machine to the remote repo using Git, invoking `gradlew` on my Linux server failed with this message:

> /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory

What happened?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The problem's cause was that Git on Windows converted the line endings of `gradlew` from Unix style (LF) to Windows style (CRLF).

You can turn off that automatic conversion using `git config core.autocrlf false`.

Setting the line endings of `gradlew` back to Unix style fixed the problem. In [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) this is done using `:set fileformat=unix`.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun - Hello. I am having the same problem. I have an Android project that was built on Windows using Android Studio. When I import in my MAC, I can not run ./gradlew clean or ./gradlew build as i get = env: bash\r: No such file or directory .  i try set fileformat=unix but does not work.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I'm using Windows as well.

Comment: As an additional help for Windows users, it can be done in Notepad++ using the menu item Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF)

Comment: that exactly was the problem in my case.. I am sharing my project files between windows machine and macbook

Answer (score 68):

This is because the gradlew file has Windows file-endings.

You can install `dos2unix` with `apt-get` or `yum` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix

sudo yum install -y dos2unix
```

and then use `dos2unix` to convert the line-endings

*from* `CRLF` Windows CarriageReturn + LineFeed

*to* `LF` Linux LineFeed only:

```
dos2unix ./gradlew
```

Then run your `gradlew` for a test:

```
./gradlew clean -d
```

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for the answers, these highlighted that the problem was Windows creating the gradlew, when I am on mac.

To fix this, from the directory of the app I ran the command:

`gradle wrapper`

This creates (replaces the broken) a gradle wrapper, that works! (notice it uses your local `gradle` install to fix the wrapper of the app)

Comment: Is this really an answer? Can you provide more information about what your answer does compared to all the other answers?

Comment: it runs the `gradle wrapper` cmd from the root dir, which the other answers dont..

Comment: not working ... zsh: command not found: gradle

Comment: You need gradle installed, like `brew install gradle`

Answer (score 2):

To solve it permanently for **Git checkouts on Linux and Mac**:

In your root Git repo directory add a file named `.gitattributes` with this content:

```
gradlew text eol=lf
```

More information: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

PS: Works too for `.sh` files using this entry:

```
*.sh text eol=lf
```

The entries work at checkout time and convert the line endings of these files to `LF`.

Answer (score 1):

A vendor had shipped a `gradlew` with Windows carriage returns. Opening `gradlew` in vim revealed `^M` line endings. Running `:e ++ff=dos` removed the line endings and resolved this issue.

As per https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers the problem is that Git on Windows converted the line endings of `gradlew` from Unix style (LF) to Windows style (CRLF).

the easier way to fix it is to run `gradle wrapper` from Android studio by following these steps:

1- Open the gradle panel and Click on `Execute Gradle Task`
[image: gradle panel]

2- Type `gradle wrapper`
[image: Execute Gradle Task]

3- Select `gradle wrapper` from the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Arrow then ok , it works in @macOS #BigSur[image]