# Travis CI - Android Project Build Failing

Tags: android, build, gradle, travis-ci

Reference build: https://travis-ci.org/ameer1234567890/Cevapr/builds/42053662

My .travis.yml is:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-19.1.0
    - android-19
    - platform-tools

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew
```

The error is:

```
./gradlew build connectedCheck
: No such file or directory
The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 127.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your gradlew file uses Windows style (CRLF) and Travis-ci runs on Linux that uses Unix style (LF).

Copy the gradlew file from a trusted project as https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/gradlew

or change it using a text editor as vim and disable automatic conversion. Read this answer:

Source: [Error with gradlew: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301956)

> The problem's cause was that Git on Windows converted the line endings
>   of gradlew from Unix style (LF) to Windows style (CRLF).
>
> You can turn off that automatic conversion using:
>
> `git config core.autocrlf false`
>
> Setting the line endings of gradlew back to Unix style fixed the
>   problem. In Vim this is done using:
>
> `set fileformat=unix`
>
> answered Mar 10 at 13:47 Matthias Braun

Comment: Try this, .vimrc file http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/why-is-vim-creating-files-with-dos-line-endings and file location http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

Comment: adding --global worked for me, git config --global core.autocrlf false

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/ameer1234567890/Cevapr), It helped me
and below is modification of [this](https://github.com/ameer1234567890/Cevapr/blob/master/.travis.yml) file

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-24.0.1
    - android-24
    - platform-tools
    - extra-android-support # because I'm use support library
    - extra-android-m2repository # because I'm use support library
  licenses:
    - '.+'

sudo: required

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

install: true

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
```