# Bash: /gradlew: No such file or directory (Windows)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gradle, spring-boot

I'm trying to compile a Springboot application on Amazon AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

When I try to package the application with Gradle in GitBash I get the following error message:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRepackage
bash: /gradlew: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Windows. I tried `git config core.autocrlf false` as suggested here: [Error with gradlew: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301956/error-with-gradlew-usr-bin-env-bash-no-such-file-or-directory). I still have the same issue. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions before hand:  `git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest.git
cd gs-accessing-data-rest/complete`   ? i.e. if you do `ls` now it prints out that gradlew is a file present in your current directory?

Comment: Yes I followed that step. Sorry. The command works when accessing the folder in which gradle is located: ``\gs-accessing-data-rest\complete\gradlew.bat``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with gradlew: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301956/error-with-gradlew-usr-bin-env-bash-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Try it with `./gradlew bootRepackage`

Comment: Sorry that was a transcription error in the OP. I used ``./gradlew bootRepackage`` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am also getting the same error on MAC machine in context of my project, when I am trying to run the same type of command from my Java code, and getting same error from the relative code. Looking forward for the solution of this error...